# How do I handle the event SessionSecurityTokenReceived in Global.asax?

Tags: events, global-asax, wif, windows-identity

I'm trying to set up sliding sessions in WIF and need to handle [SessionSecurityTokenReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.sessionauthenticationmodule.sessionsecuritytokenreceived.aspx).

I'm sure I'm doing something dumb here... but VS2010 keeps on telling me that `There is no applicable variable or member` in the spot illustrated below.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I've  searched high and low for actual samples of how to define the handling of this event, but I can't find a single one.

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{

    FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SecurityTokenReceived 
           += SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived;
     //         ^^^ There is no applicable variable or member
}



void SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived(object sender, SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e)
{
            DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            DateTime validFrom = e.SessionToken.ValidFrom;
            DateTime validTo = e.SessionToken.ValidTo;
            if ((now < validTo) &&
            (now > validFrom.AddMinutes((validTo.Minute - validFrom.Minute) / 2))
            )
            {
                SessionAuthenticationModule sam = sender as SessionAuthenticationModule;
                e.SessionToken =  sam.CreateSessionSecurityToken(
                    e.SessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal, 
                    e.SessionToken.Context,
                    now,
                    now.AddMinutes(2), 
                    e.SessionToken.IsPersistent);
                e.ReissueCookie = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //todo: WSFederationHelper.Instance.PassiveSignOutWhenExpired(e.SessionToken, this.Request.Url);

                // this code from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821351/how-to-set-sliding-expiration-in-my-mvc-app-that-uses-sts-wif-for-authenticati

                var sessionAuthenticationModule = (SessionAuthenticationModule)sender;

                sessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();

                e.Cancel = true;
            }
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you need the event subscription. Remove the subcription on start and just use

`SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived`

ASP.Net will wire that for you. (The module has to be named "SessionAuthenticationModule" and it is by default).

If you are working on sliding sessions, this blog post by Vittorio is pretty good: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2010/06/16/warning-sliding-sessions-are-closer-than-they-appear.aspx

Comment: Easy and works like a charm!  How can I tell the difference between events that need wiring up, and ones that don't

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining it in Global.asax, create a new class that inherits SessionAuthenticationModule:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationModule : SessionAuthenticationModule
{
   public CustomAuthenticationModule()
   {
      this.SessionSecurityTokenReceived += new EventHandler<SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs>(CustomAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived); 
   }

   void CustomAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived(object sender, SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e)
   {
      // Your code
   }
}
```

Then in your web.config, substitute the default SessionAuthentication module with your new module:

```
<modules>
   <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="CustomAuthenticationModule" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
</modules>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been struggling with some configurations lately and this saved my day (I don't have a global page), though it's not particularly in global.asax and should be maybe in some other thread, but I was unable to find this piece of information elswhere.